# Azure Windows App Service files not available across nodes

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Our application has the ability to request a generation of a file that are then downloaded by the client. We are seeing issues that when our app service has more than one node that the files generated are not available across the other nodes.

E.g.:
`POST` request to generate file and save to `d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data` is send by user from `machine-1` and is successful.

`GET` request from user to download this file is received by `machine-2`, this fails because the file cannot be found.

My reading of the microsoft docs is that anything in `d:\home` is backed by azure storage and is not local to the machine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality#file-access

> File access across multiple instances The home directory contains an
> app's content, and application code can write to it. If an app runs on
> multiple instances, the home directory is shared among all instances
> so that all instances see the same directory. So, for example, if an
> app saves uploaded files to the home directory, **those files are
> immediately available to all instances**.

But this doesn't seem to be happening, is there something else that needs configuring?

Comment: If `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` setting is unspecified or set to _false_, the `/home/` directory **will not be shared** across scale instances. By default, persistent storage is disabled and the setting is not exposed in the app settings. To enable it, set the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` app setting via the Cloud Shell or Power Shell. You can check it from this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-app-service-linux#custom-containers. If this doesn't work please give a brief overview of your project environment to reproduce the issue.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, this is a windows based app service not using containers, does this setting still apply?